# How to call a form from an element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Post with nested elements who also have different nested form (text for this example) according to a :cat variable.

To create the texts I'm using a post method create_element with a variable (cat = 1). And I would like to call an AJAX method to render the new text created into my post form.

My problem: I don't know how to call the text nested_form created directly into my AJAX method.

My code :

Post form (posts/new):

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <div class="elements">
    <%= f.fields_for :elements do |element| %>
      <%= render 'posts/element_field', f: element %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="btn_add_element_area">
    <a href="/posts/<%=@post.id%>/create_element?cat=1" data-method="patch" data-remote="true">
      <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Publish", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Post form (posts/_element_field):

```
<div class="element_form" id="element_form<%= f.object.id %>">
  <div class="undisplay">
    <%= f.number_field :cat %>
  </div>
  <%- if f.object.cat == 1 %>
    <%= f.fields_for :post_texts do |text| %>
      <%= render 'posts/elements/text_field', f: text %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Post form (posts/_text_field):

```
<%= f.text_area :content %>
```

Post controller (create_element) :

```
def create_element
  if params[:cat] == "1"
    @element = Element.create(post: @post, cat: 1)
    Text.create(element: @element)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render 'elements/create'}
  end
end
```

And the AJAX method (elements/create) :

```
$('.elements').append("<%=  j render partial: 'posts/element_field', locals: {f: @element} %>");
```

Error =  undefined method `object'

The problem is that in the AJAX file I call the @element created for my f variable instead of calling the form of this @element.

I also tried something like that for the AJAX method, but still not working :

```
<% form_for(@element) do |elm| %>
  $('.elements').append("<%=  j render partial: 'posts/element_field', locals: {f: elm} %>"); 
<% end %>
```

Error = undefined method `element_path'

Or

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |p| %>
  <%= p.fields_for :elements, @element do |elm| %>
    $('.elements').append("<%=  j render partial: 'posts/element_field', locals: {f: elm} %>"); 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

No error but nothing happen

If you have any ideas to solve that, I would really appreciate !

PS: And ideas to improve the question title are welcome !!

Comment: Is this typo: `partial: 'elements/element_field'`? Should it not be `posts/element_field`? Because you have different named file: `Post form (posts/_element_field):`

Comment: Yep, my mistake. I'm changing it right now, thanks. But it did't solve my problem

Comment: `Error = undefined method \`element_path'` seems like it's calling `element_path` somewhere in your code. Looking at your code above, I don't see any instances of where this `element_path` is called. Can you provide the error stacktrace? and also show the corresponding code?

Comment: This error occurs when I try to implement the form_for in my AJAX method (last piece of code)

Comment: In your last code attempt which you said "no error", should it be `<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |p| %>` instead of `<%= form_for(@post) do |p| %>`, not sure if that makes any difference though :)

Comment: Additionally using your last-code-attempt which you said "no error", can you change into `@element = Element.create!(...)` instead of `@element = Element.create(...)`, just in case there were validation errors and that the element-creation silently failed (thus `elm.object.id` will become `nil`)

Comment: Ok thanks for these advices, but I still have no changes with these modifications

Comment: Actually you can refactor your last-code-attempt into `<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |p| %>
  <%= p.fields_for :elements, @element do |elm| %>
    $('.elements').append("<%=  j render partial: 'posts/element_field', locals: {f: elm} %>"); 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
`

Comment: Thanks, these is much more cleaner ! I edit my code right now

Comment: Seems like everything's ok. Maybe something's wrong with the JS response? or that it's not being appended by JQuery properly? So, can you show the response body of your AJAX request? Should look like this:  https://pasteboard.co/HjChbHg.png

Comment: Yep sure = https://pasteboard.co/HjCinJU.png

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `response-body`, Can you click `Response` tab there on the screenshot? and copy-paste that in your code above?